# Vertical Accordion Navigation Bar Using CSS3

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Created a vertical accordion like navigation bar using pure `css3`. Everything is working fine and i just wanted to add a transition to it.

Tried it using `-webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in;` but nothings happening.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Aq6L/).

Please help me in animating it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are transitioning the `height` but there is no `height` assigned to the `.sub-menu`, and also, you cannot transit a `display: none;` element, so assign `height: 0;` to `.sub-menu`

```
.sub-menu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Aq6L/1/)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Aq6L/2/) (**Better** transitioning on collapse)

You don't require `display: none;` and `display: block;` as `height: 0;` and `overflow: hidden;` will suffice your needs.

Comment: Oh. That's where the mistake was. I got a better understanding now. Thanks for the briefing. And can i get another help from you? +1 vote for you. This is my first vote :)

Comment: @user2549787 you welcome, even I voted your question already as you've attempted to code, unlike others who just ask for solutions.. and thank you :) and ya sure, you can throw a question..

Comment: This [**POST**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158692/twitter-bootstrap-3-navigation-bar-using-affix). I'm seriously having a hard time on it. No one's looking at it. I tried everything that's possible to my knowledge. But couldn't get it.

Comment: @user2549787 Sorry but am not getting your question there, may be that's why you didn't got any answers, try to edit and simplify that..

Comment: Hope so [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160088/fixed-navigation-bar-using-twitter-bootstrap-3) is clear now.