# Fixed Navigation Bar using Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `Twitter Bootstrap 3` for my website. I'd like to have a fixed navigation bar which needs to be on after some certain point where the user scrolls down.

I've used `Affix()` and i can get the navigation bar to appeared at some certain point.

But the challenge is when the user scrolls down, the navigation bar appears on the top and the width of the navigation bar is not 100%.

I wanted the width of the navigation bar to be 100% even after scrolling the page.

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ShL4T/2/).

Please scroll down in the result segment and notice navigation bar.

It disappears and then appears at some scroll point. But the width of the navigation bar is not the same when it was at the beginning.

Please help me in fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `width: 100%;` on `.navigation`

```
.navigation {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ShL4T/4/)

Comment: You just added that 100% width?

Comment: But why didn't it work when i tried? I was doing it the whole day.

Comment: @user2549787 I actually hate bootstrap so I don't know that much about it.. but if you were trying this and still it was not working than god knows what happened hehe :)

Comment: :) Anyways i got it working now. Can you please let me know how can i add a transition over there? Like a making it to appear smoothly using `ease-in` or any effects.

Comment: @user2549787 wait I'll try :)

Comment: @user2549787 am able to transit the element but opacity is stucked, try reading docs.. it may help you out :)

Comment: Okay i'll give a try. Thank you very much for the help. And I found out where the exact error was.